Use usb path of an usb nic address in udev rules in order to assign an interface name instead of mac address
Related to:

Debian 12 - All of sudden my USB3 Lan adapter get assigned random mac address each reboot
Use parrent attribute "serial" in UDEV configuration to assign lan interface another name instead of relying on the mac address

The problem with the second provided solution is that some USB3 NICs share for some weird reasons the same ATTR{serial} so my last resort in order to rename this interfaces is the usb path.
Because this attached NICs are always in the same position and place on a USB3 hub I tough that could be useful use the usb path to identify and rename the interfaces.
lsusb says:
...
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
...

Sadly as always the things that should be intuitive doesn't work as the way expected.
I found that my interfaces are all on bus 2 and have various devnum from 5 to 10
So I tried with commands like this:
SUBSYSTEM="net", ACTION="add", DRIVERS="?*", ATTRS{busnum}="2", ATTRS{devnum}="5", ATTR{dev_id}="0x0", ATTR{type}="1", KERNEL="eth*", NAME="lan1"

But it doesn't work.
Also with this using the KERNELS path on a device that says to be in KERNELS="2-3:1.0":
SUBSYSTEM="net", ACTION="add", DRIVERS="?*", KERNELS="2-3:1.0", ATTR{dev_id}="0x0", ATTR{type}="1", KERNEL="eth*", NAME="lan1"

But nothing, the interfaces are not renamed...
Just why this rules doesn't work ?

== is a comparison, = is an assignment. I don't know if it's enforced or not (so if actually the answer in the 2nd link is wrong or not), but that's what is documented Eg: do you want to "assign" net to SUBSYSTEM or to check if it's the "net" subsystem? etc.

Found the problem, It was a syntax error as stated by @A.B basically I was using = instead of == that was used for assigning values instead of reading and comparing the content.
By using == as operator everything works fine.

Sadly if you have my same problem with this nic interfaces please check the definitive and working solution here that allows you to user original mac based address udev rules: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/774865/
