How to reset status of a network adapter before assigning the name in a udev ruleset?
Part 4 of the problem with the usb3 nic interfaces after debian 6.1.0-20 kernel update.
See the other posts here:

Debian 12 - All of sudden my USB3 Lan adapter get assigned random mac address each reboot
Use parrent attribute "serial" in UDEV configuration to assign lan interface another name instead of relying on the mac address
Use usb path of an usb nic address in udev rules in order to assign an interface name instead of mac address

Abstract:
A recent update of debian with kernel 6.1.0-20 broke the recognizing of the mac address stored inside the usb-lan nics EEPROMs so that all the udev rules written previously with the ATTR{address} (changing the interface name based on mac address) do not work anymore.
Now why this post:

using the ATTRS{serial} did work but I have 3 adapters out of 6 that shares the same "serial" attribute, hence isn't possible determine which is which.
I tried at this point to use the USB's ATTRS{busnum} and ATTRS{devnum} to identify specifically the 3 remaining interfaces however it seems that this values are not stable and change time to time by removing the mains ac current and putting it back.

So none of the above solution actually solved the very end problem.
However it seems that if you put down and up (or maybe only up) the eth interfaces with commands like:
ip link set dev eth0 down
ip link set dev eth0 up

eth0 aka the usb3 lan adapter read back the correct mac address stored in the EEPROM...
At this point my only idea is:

Can I put down/up all the interfaces so that they get the correct mac address and make udev reapply the rules back again or it is only a thing that happens once at boot time? In case is possible, Can you help me to write a script that is able to put down -> up eth from 0 to 10 and then recall back udev so that the interfaces can be renamed.

or...

Being able to refresh the ETHs down/up before the very main time that udev is called, when the interfaces already got back their original mac address and in this case udev should do its job.

The solution with RUN+= that you were suggesting last time @A.B is related to this?

Description
To fix the current state, following OP's idea, I made a single udev rule that:

only when all of these conditions are met:

adding
a network device
with driver ax88179_178a
created with a random MAC address (addr_assign_type=1)


will:

set the interface UP (thus getting the driver to retrieve the permanent MAC address property)

set it back DOWN (that's the expected state of a newly added interface)

if the interface is confirmed to now have retrieved its permanent MAC address (addr_assign_type=0), retrigger an addition of the interface
... thus triggering a new round with the appropriate renaming of the interface. (eg: when nothing else tells otherwise, usually USB network interfaces get renamed from their MAC address as enx...)




Rule and activation
Create a rule with a low enough priority (I chose 40)
/etc/udev/rules.d/40-local-net-ax88179_178a.rules:
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTR{addr_assign_type}=="1", DRIVERS=="ax88179_178a", \
  RUN="/bin/ip link set %k up", RUN+="/bin/ip link set %k down", \
  RUN+="/bin/udevadm trigger -s net -a addr_assign_type=0 -p INTERFACE=%k -c add"


Then the first time only, either (from heavier to lightest effect):

reboot

or restart udev:
systemctl restart udev


and either unplug/replug USB devices

or reload driver
rmmod ax88179_178a
modprobe ax88179_178a


or artificially trigger the new rule only on interfaces needing a fix
udevadm trigger -v -s net -p ID_NET_DRIVER=ax88179_178a -a addr_assign_type=1 -c add

If the interface was already brought UP (eg: by a networking tool such as NetworkManager), it might require not checking its MAC address type and doing just:
udevadm trigger -v -s net -p ID_NET_DRIVER=ax88179_178a -c add





Additional Notes

this will have in the end the same number of device resets as before the patch avoiding such device reset to happen: two, because the interface gets an additional UP (then DOWN) that does trigger such reset.
Thus when compiling a kernel anyway, reverting the patch is still simpler. When one needs SecureBoot and can't sign the resulting kernel module then this workaround is useful.
An actual 3rd driver patch would still be welcome.

RUN commands

The first RUN command MUST be used.

The second RUN command SHOULD be used to have the same outcome as when running with a kernel driver that handles the NIC properly: an added interface in state DOWN. One could ponder not setting it DOWN and leaving it UP, sparing one device reset, if later networking tools can cope with that

The last RUN command MAY possibly be skipped: it might not be needed if the interface is already renamed by a later networking tool relying only on the MAC address.

loop won't happen because:

if the interface got the permanent MAC address: no action
if the interface once brought up then down still didn't get the permanent MAC address (ie: the workaround didn't work), then the add action won't be performed (because it's restricted to a permanent-MAC-address device), leaving the device with a random MAC address






Other distributions than Debian

Be sure /bin/ip exists or replace it with a correct path (eg: /sbin/ip)

eudev (Devuan, Gentoo ...): I don't know if eudev behaves the same as systemd's udev when triggering an event from within. The 3rd RUN might need a change.



If for some reason additional conditions have to be added, as the ...S match variants (for a parent property) must all be part of the same parent, DRIVERS=="ax88179_178a" could be replaced by ATTRS{product}=="AX88179" for a similar effect if needed (and if the specific USB device does actually match this property) to reach alternate useful properties from an other parent (such as ATTRS{serial}).

There's at least also addr_assign_type=3 that appears to mean the MAC address has been changed (manually or otherwise, eg: setting the interface as bond slave). This rule won't touch this (nor should it, nor would it encounter this case)

documentation used

udev(7)
udevadm(8)
files in /lib/udev/rules.d/ as examples




Works like a charm. I have one question, in the case they will fix the kernel in next versions this can be still be leaved here right? because you inserted the addr_assign_type==1 check at the beginning so it will trigger back only in case of random mac address initializing. Am I correct? PS: do you think they already know of the bug or we have to report it? Thanks

Indeed once fixed the condition won't match (there will be a permanent mac address) and the rule won't have any effect anymore

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1069082 (with links to upstream etc.)

Thank you so much. I wanted also to ask, regarding the AX88179 devices I found another interesting behaviour, respect to debian 9 in debian 12 they throw a TON of interrupts 120/121 that converts in /proc/softirqs NET_RX interrupt id. What I can tell is that trying to balance this interrupt among 2 cpu is not possible and the number of them is huge, in debian9 this isn't happening but when I reinstalled debian moving to ver 12 the probably updated driver works not as good as the one in debian 9. The result is the CPU loads very high limiting transfer rate. Should i report it?

@user3450548 no idea. You might want to test a few kernels (eg: starting with Debian 10's and Debian 11's) to figure out if the change of behavior is recent or not. Else your report might just not be interesting enough to spend resources on it.

I see however it would be impossible in my custom config, so I would maybe try to track down the interface and see if is possible investigate until I found the reason of this massive interrupts. I'm using 2 of this adapters to "join" 2 network together, they forward packets and are analyzed by nftables before being sent the weird things is that NET_TX is super low NET_RX is huge.

This commit: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=56f78615bcb1c3ba58a5d9911bad3d9185cf141b appeared 4 days ago. This might be the final fix. If I understand reset again at probe, and no more at UP.
